# Is this grammatically correct? I am not sure of the sentence structure. "She saw two boys in white dresses standing by the road?"

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement, descriptive-grammar, grammaticality

I am kinda confused of the participial phrase in that sentence. Is that grammatically correct? Do I need to put a comma? Does the sentence make sense?

Comment: It implies that "she", while in some unspecified location, observed two boys, and these boys were standing adjacent to the road. The boys were (oddly) wearing white dresses.  If this is what you intended then sentence is grammatical and makes sense.

Comment: @HotLicks I agree that the "boys in white dresses" phrase is odd, not linguistically but culturally. I wonder if Edward means "boys in white robes". If it was a Friday and the boys were Muslims then this would not be odd at all.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is correct and grammatical.

It is also ambiguous, because it is unclear whether the structure "*standing by the road*" is qualifying "*she*" or *"the boys*" (although its position suggests the latter).

But there is nothing wrong about the sentence's grammar per se.

Comment: It may be _technically_ ambiguous, but few native speakers would understand the phrase as referring to _her)_.